# Capturing sp_executesql statement in sql profiler

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, profiler

After catching some data in a SQL Profiler session, I can almost always see a second entry of type `RPC:Completed` for each query using a `sp_executesql` statement. I know that this is done to create re-usable execution plan by reducing the query with parametrization.

e.g.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT s.* FROM s WHERE s.C= @O',
@O uniqueidentifier',
@O='11112222-4444-3333-1212-5555666677'
```

Duration: `10 ms`

Next entry:

```
SELECT s.* FROM s WHERE s.C= @O
```

Duration: `10 ms`

Looking at the total `sum(Duration)` of the profiler events, do I have to count both of those? The query was executed once, so 10 ms was the correct result. Instead the total result is 20 ms, with I think is just WRONG and a program-error of Profiler. Do I have to filter one of them away anyhow and how?

Comment: The RPC completed event will the total for the entire request.  What is the event class of the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Looks like those are of type SP:StmtCompleted 
( I have saved the results to a table and there is a column EventClass. Values of the SELECT Statements is 45. I have joined this with      sys.trace_events.trace_event_id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to count both. As you see, you get an rpc completed for sp_executesql. Your Select which shows up as StmtCompleted is a "subtask" of the rpc. The SQL trace already has the sum of all statements inside a rpc summed up for you.